# Best way to simulate a domain?

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I am going to build a website on a test server that will behave differently depending on which domain is used to access it (The real website will have multiple domains pointing to it).

But how will I be able to simulate the different domains on the test server?

Comment: We will need to have more information to answer this one. Like what OS are you talking about. And what kind of webserver do you use?

Comment: @RJD22 I am using LAMP (Lunix/Apache/MySQL/PHP)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just create fake domains pointing to your localhost in /etc/hosts file.

For example,

```
127.0.0.1   localhost domain1.com domain2.com
```

On Windows, this file is,

```
WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DRIVERS\ETC\HOSTS
```

Comment: Thanks, do you know where the file would be on ubantu/linux? Thanks!

Comment: to search for the file just type: `find / -name hosts`

Comment: This works locally, but the only way I can reach it from another machine is if I do http://linux-server. I tried adding domain1.com to the second line 127.0.1.1 but still no luck.

Answer (score 4):

you will need to edit your hosts file like ZZ Coder is saying. But to point the domain to a certain map you will need to edit the `httpd.conf` files. I add these kind of redirects in my `httpd-vhosts.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName yourfakedomain.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/"
    <Directory /var/www/html/>
    Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

try to edit you hosts file
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_file